# Sending struct through POST to php

Tags: php, swift, struct

I have an iOS app that is written in Swift.

The app has a cart, with items of a struct called `Order`, which has a `productName` inside it.

When the order is finished, I am sending the data to a php file, so I can upload the data to my database.

The problem is, when I send the variable `order` containing the users wishes products with the `Order` struct, and then I get the variable on the PHP page like so:

```
$order = $_POST["order"];
```

When I `echo $order;` this is the response I get in the console of Xcode:

```
responseString = Optional("[MyAppName.Order]")
```

This is my Order struct:

```
struct Order: Codable {
   let productName: String
   let productQuantity: Int
   let productPrice: Int

   init(productName: String, productQuantity: Int, productPrice: Int) {
      self.productName = productName
      self.productQuantity = productQuantity
      self.productPrice = productPrice
   }

}
```

I guess I need to change the struct so it can be read in a PHP file. **What can I do to change the data in the struct so it will be readable for a PHP file?**

Comment: As far as I know, PHP does not support Optionals. Its an interpreted, loosely typed language. How are you serializing your `Order` struct for sending it to your server via POST? Does your `Order` struct conform to `Codable`, and are you using an `Encoder` to encode it into JSON?

Comment: I'm guessing that you are trying to manually convert your struct to strings, and getting a string containing "Optional()" in your Swift conversion code.

Comment: Please edit your question to better explain what's going on and the problem you are having.

Comment: How would PHP know what a Struct from Swift is? And let alone be able to unwrap and use it? Those are two different languages. You need to send the data in some common format, like JSON, for example.

Comment: @DuncanC the struct is a Codable

Comment: @M.Eriksson that makes sense! How can I "refactor" my struct so it will be readable in json, that I can send to a POST variable?

Comment: You don't show how you are sending the data to the php server, but since Order is Codable you can encode it as JSON in your POST request. on the php side, `json_decode` will create a php object out of whatever data was sent. You do not need to formally define the data type on the php side, but you can create a class that takes the JSON in its constructor.

Comment: Alternately, if you are starting a project that is big, and will last a long time, and the api will go through many revisions, now might be the time to learn about gRPC.

Comment: @Jerry that makes sense too. How can I create a class that I can use for the json I get on the php site?

Comment: You really don't have to, except as a way to make your code clearer. In php, you can take any valid JSON, call `json_decode`, and you will have an object that is a faithful representation of whatever was there. I prefer to define classes in php that have `__construct(string $jsonData)` (or something like that) to formally parse the data into a well-defined object. But in php, well-defined is purely optional.

Comment: Well thank you! I will definitely give it a try with json. It makes sense!